# QuerySelectorAll styling colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

I am currently working on some Sharepoint customizations with JavaScript.

The idea is to transform "p" elements into traffic lights R/Y/G.

Sample code:

```
var oddColumn = document.querySelectorAll('td.ms-rteTableOddCol-default p');
var evenColumn = document.querySelectorAll('td.ms-rteTableEvenCol-default p');

function checkOddColumns() {
for (var i = 0; i < oddColumn.length; i++){
if (oddColumn[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Y") >= 1 && oddColumn[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Y") < 20) {
    oddColumn[i].style.color = "yellow";
    oddColumn[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    oddColumn[i].style.border = "1px solid yellow";
    oddColumn[i].style.borderRadius = "50%";
    oddColumn[i].style.width = "20px";
    oddColumn[i].style.height = "20px";
    oddColumn[i].style.marginLeft = "auto";
    oddColumn[i].style.marginRight = "auto";
}
```

Now the problem is, that I have found querySelectorAll is better suited to my needs, but I've previously used getElementsByClassName with no problems. However, once I replaced getElementsByClassName as querySelectorAll, backgroundColor and color stopped changing and have always defaulted to black text/white background.

I have no idea why this does not work considering if I do this without a loop, by manually targeting the elements through console, it works perfectly. The problem occurs when doing it in the loop.

Is there some problem with the code / something I should try, or is it just Sharepoint being pain in the ass again?

Comment: querySelectorAll does not return an array instead an node list hence this loop won't iterate

Comment: @VinodLouis `querySelectorAll()` returns an array-like object, as does `getElementsByClassName()`. For both lists you have to use a loop to iterate over the elements.

Comment: When do you call `.querySelectorAll(...)`? After or before the `td.ms-rteTableOddCol-default` elements exist? `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a live collection which will be automatically updated after calling it so it won't be necessary to wait for the elements to exist (example: https://jsfiddle.net/k2yo561m/1/ ).

Comment: I call querySelectorAll obviously after the elements exist.

The problem is, that all other "styles" are being updated except for color and backgroundColor, which are defaulting to black/white values all the time. All other styles, such as border, height, width, all update and change.

Comment: @RusselB And if you revert your code back to `getElementsByClassName` the color and backgroundColor are changing again?

Comment: Yes.

False alarm, I have found the error in the code. The if condition check was faulty and must have been changed accordingly. I'm terribly sorry for causing the rucus.

I have changed it to check if "R", "G" or "Y" are === 0 and it worked.

On another note, this loop managed to completely break and crash Chrome and IE, so I guess I won't be using this code for the moment. 

Very big thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in this line

```
if (oddColumn[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Y") >= 1 && oddColumn[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Y") < 20) {
```

The if condition check should've been modified accordingly after using querySelectorAll instead of getElementsByClassName. After changing

```
oddColumn[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Y") >= 1 && oddColumn[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Y") < 20) {
```

to simply

```
oddColumn[i].innerHTML.indexOf("Y") === 0 {
```

the code started to work